# clean install of Lubuntu 13.10 : firefox not localized

Tags: 13.10, firefox, lubuntu, localization

It seem's that Firefox intalled by default with Lubuntu 13.10 is not localized (in french for my case).

I performed a clean install ( booting live on Usb key, and then installing, using french language,and choosed not to keep anything on hard disk )

I have "FR" on systray, and on synaptic, I can see that "firefox-locale-fr" is installed ( but "firefox-locale-en" is installed too.

Any clue to get firefox in french ?

**[edit]** : suggestion from ark :
- *remove firefox-locale-en* has no effect.
- language support is already in french. I changed language order to get french canadian just under french and not at end of list... nothing changed..

I thing that something is wrong but just with firefox : other default tools are well localized : pidgin, gnumeric , abiworld...

**[edit]** : installig "local switcher" plugin : show me only english choice.

problem was solved after installing latest updates : Firefox was automatically switched in french after reboot, and "local switcher" plugin show me more choices : : English US+england+south africa, french

Answer (score 0):

1. Try removing `firefox-locale-en`

> sudo apt-get remove firefox-locale-en
>
> open Language support and choose French..